# Top vertical align in line-height (or vertical spacing without line-height)

Tags: vertical-alignment, css

I have a multi-line title side by side to an icon. I would like to keep the line-height of that title at about 1.6 . If I do so though, the text does not align on top because it stays vertically centered to the line. The result is that the top of the icon is not aligned with the top of the text. If I use line-height 1 the problem does not occur because the middle vertical alignment of a text in a line of the same size is the same as the top alignment.

You can see what I mean in this [code pen](http://cdpn.io/zAter).

Any idea?

Comment: You can add a negative top margin to your title.

Comment: That works, however I was hoping for a more clean solution to align on top (so I don't need to know how much to put on the margin). Anyway perhaps this is the only way.

Comment: You can define your font-size in `em` and the negative top margin in `em` as well, that way you will achieve alignment regardless of what font size is inherited.

Comment: The issue is understandable without any code.

Comment: Yes it is true, I will go for a -0.3em margin top. @Nit copy the comment to an answer so I can accept it

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I put the code pen for that reason

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela While yes, for someone with a typography background the question may be very poorly worded as a developer I think the wording is sufficient, it's possible to answer the question within the limitations of web technologies used today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a negative top margin to your title.
Defining both your font size and the margin in `em` will allow you to achieve alignment regardless of what font size is inherited.